# Why when I set the value of an hidden input to a value of an array of objects it makes every item in the hidden input array into [object Object]

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, javascript-objects

I have this code:

```
for(let i =0; i < upbtn.length; i++){
  upbtn[i].addEventListener('click', function(){
    let whichTopic = i
    if(whichTopic == 0){
      return true
    }
    else{
      let arr = coursenewtopics.value
      arr = JSON.parse(arr)
      arraymove(arr, i, i-1)
      coursenewtopics.value = arr
      console.log(arr)
      console.log(coursenewtopics.value)
      //changeordertopicsform.submit()
    }
  })
}
```

I am trying to sort an array from an hidden input then set the value of the hidden input to the sorted array, I console logged the results from the sorted array(arr)

```
[
    {
        "type": "text",
        "name": "",
        "text": ""
    },
    {
        "type": "text",
        "name": "2",
        "text": ""
    },
    {
        "type": "text",
        "name": "1",
        "text": ""
    },
    {
        "type": "text",
        "name": "3",
        "text": ""
    },
    {
        "type": "text",
        "name": "4",
        "text": ""
    }
]
```

and the results are what I want, however when after I put this value I just logged of arr to the hidden input, then console log the value of the hidden input becomes:

```
[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object]
```

why does JavaScript act this? how do I fix this an put the values into the hidden input without making them go [object Object]? I need them for a form later on.

Thanks!

Comment: What is `coursenewtopics`? A DOM element?

Comment: because `({}).toString()` (any object) results in the string `"[object Object]"`

Comment: @RShields it is an hidden input of whom value is an array of the objects I am sorting then putting back.

Comment: @Bravo but I am not using the toString() method...?

Comment: since `coursenewtopics.value` is JSON and `arr` is the parsed object from that JSON, use `coursenewtopics.value`

Comment: no, but `input.value` must be a string, so assigning a non-string to it implies calling `.toString()` on the value being assigned

Comment: My suspicion is that `coursenewtopics` has an implicit requirement that its `value` be a string, in which case `toString` would be called on anything you try to set as its `value`. In order to avoid this issue, you might have to JSONify both when setting and getting `value`

Comment: @RSheilds then how do I fix that it automatically turns it into a string? I cant really stop doing it...

Comment: OH I FOUND A WAY TO DO IT!
I used JSON.stringify(arr) to turn it into a string to put back into the hidden input without messing it up!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so your problem is 'How to display an array of object literally'.

you can try `JSON.stringify(arr, null, '  ')`